# Import sprite settings in unity will not save. Pixel art issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite-sheet

Not so much a coding question as much as a unity UI question, but I don't know where else to ask.

I am saving a pixel art sprite sheet in unity. I need it to be point (no filter) and multiple, but whenever I click off the image, it does not save and reverts back to the settings with bilinear filter mode and single sprite mode

The "Apply" button under the format option was something I saw in pixel art tutorials for unblurring the pixel art, but it does not appear as an option when I change the filter mode and Sprite mode.

How can I get these settings to save? Why is this happening? Thanks!

Comment: You need to click `Apply` in order to save the settings.  It is found at the very bottom of the texture import settings inspector.  Scroll to the very bottom of the window.

Comment: @hijinxbassist I believe there is only 1 apply button which is the one below the format option, which as I said doesn't work...

Comment: Is the Apply button greyed out / disabled?

Comment: Sorry for late response @hijinxbassist its greyed out until I change the format option. I want my format as the RGBA 32 (I believe thats what it is called) which saves, just not the other options